# Laravel Image Update

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-5, laravel-5.5, laravel-5.6

I'm doing a Admin Panel in Laravel 5.6 and I have a problem where productController --resource update.

My store as this:

```
if($request->hasfile('filename'))
        {
        $file = $request->file('filename');        
        $name=$file->getClientOriginalName();        
        $image_resize = Image::make($file->getRealPath());              
        $image_resize->resize(590, 590);
        $image_resize->save(public_path('/images/urunler/' .$name));
        } 
        $urun = new Urun();
        $urun->k_id=$request->get('k_id'); 
        $urun->ad=$request->get('ad'); 
        $urun->form=$request->get('form');
        $urun->icerik=$request->get('icerik');                
        $urun->ticari_sekli=$request->get('ticari_sekli');
        $urun->filename=$name;
        $urun->save(); 

        return redirect('/urunler')->with('success','Ürün Başarı İle Eklendi.');
```

and My Update as this:

```
$urun= Urun::findOrFail($id);  
$urun->update($request->all());

if ($request->hasFile('filename'))
{
    $file = $request->file('filename');        
    $name=$file->getClientOriginalName();        
    $img = Image::make($file->getRealPath());              
    $img->resize(590, 590);                                                                         
    $img = Image::make($file->getRealPath())->resize(590, 590)->insert(public_path('/images/urunler/' .$name));                                                 
    $img->save(public_path('/images/urunler/' .$name));   
    $urun->image = $name;                        
}   
$urun->save();
return redirect('/urunler')->with('success','Ürün Başarı İle Güncellendi.');
```

Store part is working but Update part save a filename database but image doesn't move in images/urunler.

My php version is 7.2.4 and I'm using Laravel 5.6.

Comment: check dd($request->hasFile('filename')) return false or true?

Comment: false :( How can i do?

Comment: So in request there is no file so it will never execute your if condition.

Comment: Sorry , I don't understand.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Delete these codes.

```
$img = Image::make($file->getRealPath())->resize(590, 590)->insert(public_path('/images/urunler/' .$name));                                                 
$img->save(public_path('/images/urunler/' .$name));
```

After that. Add these codes.

```
$location = public_path('/images/urunler/'.$name);
Image::make($file->getRealPath())->resize(590, 590)->save($location);
```

Give it a try.

Solution: Change related codes like that.

```
$location = public_path('/images/urunler/'.$name);
Image::make($file->getRealPath())->resize(590, 590)->save($location);
$urun->filename= $name;
```

Then add

```
 $this->validate(request(),[ 
 'k_id' => 'required',
 'ad' => 'required',
 'form' => 'required',
 'icerik' => 'required',
 'ticari_sekli' => 'required',
 'filename'=>'required' ]);
```

PS: filename must be just required. Not required|image. It isn't an image. Its just name. 
After that request filename. Like that: `$urun->filename= $name;`

don't `$urun->image= $name;`. Because there is no `$urun->image`.

Comment: Same eror , The name is registered in the database but not moved to the file

Comment: my last question is: 
have you tried dd($request->hasFile('filename'));
if it return false you didn't validate filename. add this to top of the function. Or you can't get it somehow.

Comment: false :( How can i do?

Comment: I'm doing store an update this;

$this->validate(request(),[        
            'k_id' => 'required',
            'ad' => 'required',
            'form' => 'required',
            'icerik' => 'required',
            'ticari_sekli' => 'required',
            'filename'=>'required|image'
        ]);
but isn't do

Comment: you just passing the file name intead of content.

Comment: Like i said. You are missing validate the file. You are trying to pass filename. Add 'file'=>'required' and add $urun->filename = $name;
My answer was updated.

Answer (score 0):

This works for me:

```
if ($request->file('filename')) {
        $file = $request->file('filename');
        $destinationPath = $_SERVER['DOCUMENT_ROOT'] . '/images/urunler/';
        $file->move($destinationPath, 'FILENAME.' . $file->getClientOriginalExtension());
}
```

Just edit `FILENAME` to the name of the file you want or replace `FILENAME` with `$file->getClientOriginalName();`

The file wil be saved in the public/images/urunler/ folder

**EDIT:**

Last thing i can think of would be this: in the form open tag place `enctype="multipart/form-data"`. What this says is that your form exists of normal data AND possible files. There might still be files are not allowed so also place `files="true"`in the form open.

Comment: I edited the answer with extra info and a possible fix. @OğuzKorkmaz